# Funcionamiento de ng-change en angularJs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un select muy sencillo para probar ng-change. No funciona con ninguna función que ponga. He dejado el alert por simplicidad.
¿Qué hago mal?
Tampoco encuentro ejemplos de su uso
Paso el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PruebaController">

      <select ng-model="miProvinciaSeleccionada" 
        ng-options="provincia as provincia.nombre for provincia in provincias track by provincia.idProvincia"
        ng-change="alert('HOLA')" >
        <option value="">--Elige opcion--</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      El nombre de la provincia seleccionada es:{{miProvinciaSeleccionada.nombre}}

</body>

</html>

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("PruebaController", function($scope) {
  $scope.provincias=[
    {
      idProvincia:2,
      nombre:"Castellón"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:3,
      nombre:"Alicante"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:1,
      nombre:"Valencia"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:7,
      nombre:"Teruel"
    },  
    {
      idProvincia:5,
      nombre:"Tarragona"
    }
  ];

  $scope.miProvinciaSeleccionada={
      idProvincia:3,
      nombre:"Alicante"
    }

});
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que has  asociado a la directiva `ng-change` una expresion que no es una [Expresion de AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Para que funcione debes crear esta expresión, por ejemplo, una función en el controlador que sea un "wrapper" de tu expresión JavaScript.

Por ejemplo, asi:

**html**

```
ng-change="miAlert()"
```

**Controlador**

```
$scope.miAlert = function() {
    alert('HOLA')
}
```

Talvez quieras ver [Expresiones AngularJS vs Expresiones JavaScript](https://docs.angularjs.org/api#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una función  asociada al **$scope** para que te la reconozca y usarla en el **ng-change**. Lee la documentación de [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("PruebaController", function($scope) {
  $scope.provincias=[
    {
      idProvincia:2,
      nombre:"Castellón"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:3,
      nombre:"Alicante"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:1,
      nombre:"Valencia"
    },
    {
      idProvincia:7,
      nombre:"Teruel"
    },  
    {
      idProvincia:5,
      nombre:"Tarragona"
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.ShowAlert = function (){
    alert("Se selecciono La provincia: " + $scope.miProvinciaSeleccionada.nombre);
  }

  $scope.miProvinciaSeleccionada={
      idProvincia:3,
      nombre:"Alicante"
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PruebaController">

      <select ng-model="miProvinciaSeleccionada" 
        ng-options="provincia as provincia.nombre for provincia in provincias track by provincia.idProvincia"
        ng-change="ShowAlert()" >
        <option value="">--Elige opcion--</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      El nombre de la provincia seleccionada es:{{miProvinciaSeleccionada.nombre}}

</body>

</html>
```